# Codeigniter, say cheese jquery not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm having problems with this `webcam plugin`.

I can access the camera and thake the picture, however, cannot save it. When I `click` to `record` (Guardar Foto) it has no action

I'm going to show my code here.

My View

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>WebCam</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <style type="text/css">

        #content{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1000px;
            position: relative;

        }

        .fotografia{
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
            border: 20px solid #333;
            background: #eee;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;

        }

        .marca {
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 10px;
            bottom: -16px;
            left: 152px;

        }

        #obturador,#guardarFoto{
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid;
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-left: 50px;

        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <div id="webcam" class="fotografia">
                <span class="marca">tutoriales.com</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <div id="say-cheese-snapshots" class="fotografia">
                <span class="marca">Snapshots</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <span id="obturador">Tomar foto</span>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:50%">
            <span id="guardarFoto">Guardar Foto</span>
        </div>

        <div class="fotografia">
            <img id="fotoGuardada" src="" style="display:none" />
            <span class="marca">Foto Armazenada</span>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/say-cheese.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var img=null;
       var sayCheese = new SayCheese('#webcam',{snapshots: true});

       sayCheese.start();

       $('#obturador').bind('click', function(e){
           sayCheese.takeSnapshot(320,240);
           return false;
       })

       sayCheese.on('snapshot', function(snapshot){
           img = document.createElement('img');

           $(img).on('load', function(){
               $('#say-cheese-snapshots').html(img);
           });
           img.src = snapshot.toDataURL('image/png');
       });

        $('#guardarFoto').bind('click', function(){
         var src = img.src;
         data = {
             src: src
         }
         $.ajax({
             url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>webcam/ajax',
             data: data,
             type: 'post',
             sucess: function(respuesta) {
                 $('#fotoGuardada').attr('src', respuesta).show(500);
             }
         });
        });


    </script>
</body>
```

Now my Model

```
    <?php

class Fotos_model extends CI_Model{

public function gravarFoto($foto) {
    return $this->db->insert('fotos',array('foto'=>$foto));

}

public function getLastFoto() {
    return $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get('fotos')->row()->foto;

}

}
```

And my Controller

```
<?php

class Webcam extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(array('Fotos_model'));
}


public function index() {
        $this->load->view('webcam/index_view');
    }

    public function ajax () {
        $src = $this->input->post('src');
        $this->Fotos_model->gravarFoto($src);
        $foto = $this->Fotos_model->getLastFoto();
        $this->output->set_output ($foto);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the handler attached to `#guardarFoto` fails to trigger or that the handler fails to achieve the desired result?  Either way, I suggest you change `$('#guardarFoto').bind('click', function(){...` to `$('#guardarFoto').on('click', function(){...`

Comment: Still the same, it has no action at all. Not sure what's going on...

Comment: After the line `var src = img.src;` add this `alert("#guardarFoto clicked!");` The you can know if your handler actually got attached to the DOM element.

Comment: Ok! The alert Works, and the image goes to the DB, however, it goes with an extension ".bin" ..... and maybe that's why I can't see it, cuz it's not a valid image extension... hum.... Now Just need to fix that... Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably related to the say-cheese api. I only took a quick look at it so this may be way off base. But I think it has to do with the creation of var img. You create an 'img' element but maybe it should be a 'canvas' ?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error: You are missing a semicolon at the end of

```
data = {src: src}
```

Should be

```
data = {src: src};
```

Comment: No... Still the same... But i fixed that semicolon... Thanks

Comment: You are missing another semicolon at the end of `$('#obturador').bind(...`

Answer (score -1):

Your error is because field id must to be: key & autoincrement:

[image]

Comment: What does your image signifies here, Its not even in english